# How to set input variable as key in json while creating view in couchBase

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, couchbase, couchbase-view

I am trying to create user specific views on couchBase from Node.js. Here is the code I have

```
app.post("/todo/:id", function(req, res){
console.log("hey" + req.body.userId)
  baseview.setDesign('design_users', {
     "$req.body.userId": {
        'map': "function (doc, meta) { if(doc.toUserName == req.body.userId) {emit(doc.status, doc.title);}}"
      }
    },
    function(err, result){
        if (err != null) console.log(err);
        else res.send(result)
    }
  ); 
})
```

On executing the following curl

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"userId": "uidam231"}' http://localhost:3000/todo/id
```

Though the design document design_users is created on couchBase, the expected view (uidam231) is not. There are no errors on the console.

I suspect that the assignment of the variable req.body.userId in the json is probably the cause. Please note that the view name ("$req.body.userId": ) and the filter criteria (doc.toUserName == req.body.userId) both need the passed in variable.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to pass variable to the map function in the view, because `map()` and `reduce()` used not to query data, but rather to build the index, materialized view of the data in the bucket, and later you can do filtering, ranging, sorting, but based on the keys you have selected to put into that index during build (i.e. when map was executed). If put it simple, the database runs your map function once for whole data set, and then for each new/changed document, to update the index. This is why you cannot pass or use the parameters from the query, or it makes meaningless usage of `new Date()` or `Math.random()` in some cases, because their values will be evaluated only once for each document during index build, but not the query time.

What you should do in your case, is to build map function like this:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit(doc.toUserName, [doc.status, doc.title]);
}
```

This will give you view index, where user name is the key, and status and title is the value. So that you can query view using `key=` argument and pass there user ID.

More information:

1. [Querying Data with Views](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/architecture/querying-data-with-views.html)
2. [MapReduce Views](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/sdk/nodejs/view-queries-with-sdk.html)

Comment: Hi @avsej: I understand this part. What I am trying to achieve is this, lets say on a new user registration, I'd like to add the (user specific) view(s) to couchBase. I guess I could also run a script to add views based on each user. Essentially, this is not a query. Just a view, where the map function checks for a  certain value like say a number or string. Only that the view is inserted (just once for each new registered user) from Node.js

Comment: In this case you have to substitute username as literal into `map()` function body instead of `req.body.userId` and also into view name. But you have to keep in mind, that you cannot update/add just single view, you have to overwrite whole design document every time. Maybe N1QL would solve your issue?

Comment: NiQL seems to have higher latency over views. The differences I plan to mitigate with couchbase lite on the client. I still cant figure out converting to the literal part in the above problem.